# Select rows from table by keys

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I am looking for a way to iteratively select all sublists with the same ID (my 1st column, residual columns are `AbsoluteTime` entries). First, I obtained the list of unique IDs with `Union`. Then I want to use this list for the selection task. I assume that it must work with `Sequence` and `ReplaceAll`, but could not make it work. Here's what I have so far:

```
ticketList = Union[dataList[[1 ;;, 1]]];
tempList = Select[dataList, #1[[1]] == x &] /. x ->  Sequence[ticketList];
```

My ultimate goal is to build up a `TemporalData` array with all items which each belong to the same ID.

My data is has dimensions `n x m`. The ticket list has dimension `t`. The resulting table should have dimensions `t x i x m`, where `i` is the cardinality of items with the same ID, and the `i`'s sum to `n`. I assumed, that I can then map `TemporalData` on every `t`-th item in order to build the temporal list.

I searched the site but didn't find a previous question that seem to address my problem. Maybe I misunderstood the use cases of similiar questions.

Comment: Can you give us a small size example of the dataList that you have and of the output you desire?

Comment: GatherBy will possibly be of use: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GatherBy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt to address your question based on the sort of data I imagine you have in mind.  First, some data. Note: the integers are understood to be ID's.

```
times = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {20, 5}];
ids = RandomInteger[4, 20];
data = Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[times], ids]]
```

> {{1, 95.2049, 98.1609, 35.1946, 32.636, 81.2383}, {3, 92.8072, 
>     36.0249, 68.3793, 54.1311, 95.1051}, {3, 4.26078, 47.9919, 31.627, 
>     53.0064, 96.8995}, {4, 18.2792, 94.4752, 5.66575, 5.62435, 
>     35.8945}, {4, 67.4149, 68.1577, 25.281, 17.8322, 15.3123}, {2, 
>     77.6343, 35.3486, 81.3541, 73.6091, 51.4884}, {0, 28.5346, 29.2705, 
>     78.9446, 32.2112, 7.05296}, {4, 91.9405, 79.4176, 75.6947, 72.1069, 
>     5.94247}, {2, 11.0662, 24.4381, 79.5328, 20.2195, 79.4703}, {0, 
>     61.6779, 73.8532, 61.5861, 7.79641, 38.3836}, {4, 52.3064, 95.9954, 
>     62.3701, 34.7654, 99.8931}, {2, 92.6636, 57.8744, 23.4167, 76.3724, 
>     44.8631}, {2, 73.7149, 84.6716, 36.1234, 89.5432, 39.8183}, {3, 
>     50.4444, 7.98911, 69.4092, 96.3191, 79.6566}, {3, 41.2261, 58.5009, 
>     57.7989, 58.9187, 8.87187}, {4, 53.5552, 11.3278, 8.24034, 67.3065, 
>     19.4648}, {2, 19.9501, 30.5649, 73.9395, 13.3722, 36.5546}, {3, 
>     96.5631, 19.1948, 23.226, 92.8776, 64.4002}, {0, 65.9084, 10.2902, 
>     8.83754, 93.0831, 36.464}, {1, 18.2795, 12.4673, 42.0253, 39.8816, 
>     50.8252}}

Now to gather the records that have the same id:

```
GatherBy[data, First]//TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's exactly what I was aiming for and the absolute elegant solution. I am sorry that I did not find GatherBy in the manual. Sometimes the power of MM is really amazing / overwhelming.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Mathematica knows many useful ways to manipulate lists. BTW, if you wanted the id's to appear in standard order, you might do a `SortBy[data,First]` before GatherBy.

Comment: Actually, `Sort[data]` is sufficient if it's inside the GatherBy.

Answer (score 3):

Using @David's example data

```
 times = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {20, 5}]; 
 ids =   RandomInteger[4, 20]; 
 data = Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[times], ids]];
```

"few" more alternatives (none as elegant as David's answer):

```
 dt1 = Select[data, (#1[[1]] == x) & /. x -> #] & /@  Union[data[[All, 1]]];
 dt2 = Function[{xx}, Select[data, #[[1]] == xx &]] /@ Union@data[[All, 1]];
 dt3 = Cases[data, {#, __}] & /@ Union[data[[All, 1]]];
 dt4 = DeleteCases[data, Except[{#, __}]] & /@ Union[data[[All, 1]]];
 dt5 = Pick[data, data[[All, 1]], #] & /@ Union@data[[All, 1]];
 dt6 = Pick[data, data[[All, 1]] - #, 0] & /@ Union@data[[All, 1]];
 dt7 = SplitBy[SortBy[data, {First}], First];
 dt8 = SortBy[GatherBy[data, First], First];
 dt9 = GatherBy[SortBy[data, {First}], First];
 dt10 = Extract[data, #] & /@ Position[data, {#, __}] & /@ Union[data[[All, 1]]];
 dt11 = data[[#]] & /@ Join @@ Position[data, {#, __}] & /@ Union[data[[All, 1]]];
 dt12 = Reap[Sow[#, First[#]] & /@ SortBy[data, {First}]][[2]];
 dt1 == dt2 == dt3 == dt4 == dt5 == dt6 == dt7 == dt8 == dt9 == dt10 == dt11 == dt12
 (* True *)
```

Note: If the ordering of the elements in the sublists does not matter, `Last@Reap[Sow[#, First[#]] & /@ data]` gives the same result as `GatherBy[data,First]`:

```
 GatherBy[data,First]==Last@Reap[Sow[#, First[#]] & /@ data]
 (* True *)
```

Comment: Whatever I had you've plainly caught.  Get well soon! xD

Comment: Also, where the devil is `Sow` & `Reap`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, added `Reap[Sow[...]...]`:)

Comment: Another one for your list: `Reap[{##} ~Sow~ # & @@@ data, Union[First /@ data]][[2, All, 1]]` -- no claims of efficiency.

Comment: I think in many cases, `SortBy[data,{First}]` may  be simplified to `Sort[data]`.

Comment: @David, `Sort[data]==SortBy[data,First]`;  but `SortBy[data,First]!=SortBy[data,{First}]`, and i needed the latter to keep the original ordering of `data[[All,2;;]]`.

Comment: +1 for the usefulness of seeing a side-by-side comparison of the functions.

Comment: @kguler Your dt1 approach is what I had originally in mind. Now from your answer I know that I have to put some brackets around the first place-holder to mix #1 and # for the mapping. Thank you.